# Выборочная линковка в GCC

Tags: c, gcc, link

Как правильно организовать выборочную сборку программы в GCC?
Предположим имеется такой набор **независимых** друг от друга исходных файлов:

```
Vec2.c
Vec3.c
Mat3.c
```

, которые собираются в библиотэку`libMegaSuperMath.a`.
Ясен пень, линкуя такую библиотэку, мы включаем все ее содержимое в конечный исполняемый модуль (или не включаем?).
Как организовать выборочную линковку, в случае, если программа, использующая такую библиотэку не нуждается в некоторых из ее компонентов? Вырежет ли GCC неиспользуемые структуры, функции и данные? Какие флаги оптимизации требуются для этого?
Приемлем ли в подобной ситуации подход, при котором отдельные "классы" библиотэки собираются в объектные файлы, а инструкция сборки формируется на основании требующихся "классов"? Типа как-то так:

```
Vec2.o
Vec3.o
Mat3.o
```

и

```
cc NewUberTurboProgramm.c Vec2.o Mat3.o -o Run.exe
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нет, библиотека не линкуется безусловно и целиком. Библиотека - это архив объектных файлов, из которого берутся только "нужные" объектные файлы.

В "классическом" алгоритме линковки библиотек из библиотеки берутся те и только те объектные файлы, которые нужны *на текущий момент*. Линкер просматривает линкуемые  компоненты последовательно, слева-направо, как они указаны в командной строке линкера. В процессе такого просмотра он поддерживает список ненайденных/неразрешенных на данный момент символов (в самом начале этот список состоит из просто символа `main` или его аналога). В процессе обработки слева-направо из очередной встреченной в командной строке библиотеки берутся те и только те объектные файлы, которые разрешают какие-то из не разрешенных *на текущий момент* символов. Таким образом изъятие кода из библиотеки делается с точностью *до объектного файла*.

Так что ваше утверждение "линкуя такую библиотэку, мы включаем все ее содержимое в конечный исполняемый модуль" - не верно.

Из этого также следует, что библиотеки в командной строке линкера лучше указывать где-то в конце - когда линкер уже знает весь список неразрешенных символов и, соответственно, возьмет из библиотеки все, что надо. Если указать библиотеку в командной строке слишком рано, то может получиться так, что линкер возьмет из нее не все, что нужно, ибо в этот момент он еще не знал все, что нужно. В частности, если указать библиотеку самой первой в командной строке, из нее не возьмется вообще ничего (если библиотека не предоставляет `main`).

С прямым указанием отдельных объектных файлов в командной строке линкера ситуация иная: явно указанный объектный файл всегда безусловно целиком линкуется в программу, независимо от того, "нужен" ли он на этот момент или нет.

В традиционном "классическом" линкере добиться линковки с точностью до функции можно только помещая каждую функцию в свой отдельный объектный файл. Но многие современные компиляторы и линкеры уже поддерживают линковку с точностью до отдельной функции без необходимости такого индивидуального разбрасывания функций по файлам. В GCC это делается через LTO - link-time optimizations.

Comment: Безмерно благодарен за такой подробный ответ.
А можно в двух словах о LTO?

Comment: Достаточно ли использовать -flto, чтобы компилятор с высокой вероятностью, удалял неиспользуемый код (функции/данные внутри .o файлов)?

Comment: @Peter Levenberg: Надо экспериментировать и смотреть по месту. `-flto` должно быть достаточно, но насколько "чисто" оно чистит - я точно не знаю.

Comment: Благодарю за ответы! От души! )))